# How does pandas replace NaN values with mean value using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, fillna

I tried using this to replace the NaN values in the column feature count ( its an integer that ranges from 1 to 10 ) using groupby ( client_id or client _ name ) ,
however the NaN values do not seem to go.

```
df['feature_count'].isnull().sum()
```

The output is :

```
2254
```

Now I use:

```
df['feature_count'].fillna(df.groupby('client_name')['feature_count'].mean(), inplace=True)
```

But the output remains the same :

```
df['feature_count'].isnull().sum()

2254
```

Any other way to replace the NaN values by the means of other non NaN values of the column grouped by their IDs?

Comment: The code you use looks erroneous, especially the inplace=True part. Try to get the mean first (in a variable). When you achieve that you fill. And if you want us to solve this problem you should provide a sample of your code according to [mcve].

Comment: i have 500 Client ids, that means I would have to find the mean 500 times, isnt that a lot of work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df.groupby('client_name')['feature_count'].mean()` returns a series.

But you aren't looking to replace null values *with a series*. Instead, you want to replace null values with *a mean mapped from a series*.

Therefore, you can use the following:

```
s = df.groupby('client_name')['feature_count'].mean()
df['feature_count'].fillna(df['client_name'].map(s), inplace=True)
```

Even more Pandorable would be to utilize [`pd.DataFrame.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html), which handles the mapping part for you:

```
s = df.groupby('client_name')['feature_count'].transform('mean')
df['feature_count'].fillna(s, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, the NaN values didnt disappear completely, they reduced from 2254 to 529

Comment: @KrishnaDhruv, Guess some of your groups may be all `NaN`, have a look at your inputs. Otherwise, you'll need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yes! Some of the groups are all NaN.Thanks for the insight and the answer!!!! :))